# Locating outdoor / hiking shops which sell gas cans in Oslo?

Tags: gear, shopping, hiking, norway, oslo

In a while I will be traveling to Norway for a hiking trip. In between getting from the Oslo Gardermoen airport to Finse, I'll have to get gas cans with a that are UNEF 7/16" threaded, which means they look like this:

[image]

Any tips on where to get these? preferably at shops near the airport.

I already found Oslo sportslager, who sell these for sure: http://www.oslosportslager.no/produkt/beaver-power-gas-450-gassboks-25070.aspx

But in case they're out of it, it would be nice to have a backup plan :)

Comment: Just as a linguistic tip: in American English people usually call this a *(camping) fuel canister*.  *Gas can* usually refers to a large (1-5 gal, 4-20 l) plastic or metal container for gasoline (petrol).  (Google Image Search for "gas can" to see what I mean.)  So maybe a different title would help.  (But I have no idea what they're called in Norwegian :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called "gassboks" (gas can) in Norwegian.

I doubt that you'll find any at the airport, but if you are going by train from the airport to Finse, you'll have to change trains at Oslo Central Station and there are plenty of outdoor shops in downtown Oslo, which all are likely to have these on stock.

If the shop you're linking to is sold out, there is a Clas Ohlson store just a few houses down the street in Torggt. 6 (Oslo Sportslager is in Torggt. 20). According to their web page, they have the gas cans on stock.

Answer (score 4):

Went to Norway last week, did a lot of research to find gas canisters. We landed on Rygge on a Saturday evening, and there is a Shell not far from the railway station with a seven eleven, we bought them there. When we wanted to drop off our spare gas at the DNT hut in gjendesheim, the guy there said they have about 100 spare ones of those lying around, so if you're passing by a staffed DNT hut, call them first to hear if they have some lying around :-)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interessted, the kind of connection on these fuel canisters / gas cans is actually called a "Lindal Valve"

We where able to get them at Oslo sportslager